# Script to check for read only filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel, mount

How can I check a bunch of systems to find any filesystem that are mounted read-only? Possibly via a script?

Comment: What systems? What issue?

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Please rephrase it.

Comment: They are RHEL4 and RHEL5 systems.  The filesystem (eg /var, /tmp , /) are mounted as read only. I want to find/list which sytems have such read only issue.

Answer (score 13):

```
awk '$4~/(^|,)ro($|,)/' /proc/mounts
```

Comment: I understand the awk, but not the 'nosuid' part.  Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @user11496: I meant "ro" - I mis-pasted my test code.  I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've used the following in the past

```
grep ' ro ' /proc/mounts
```

In some instances you may want to skip any remote mounts which may be RO by design

```
grep ' ro ' /proc/mounts | grep -v ':'
```

You also may want to skip things that are mounted via automount

```
grep ' ro ' /proc/mounts | egrep -v 'automount|autofs'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you intent is to find filesystems with problems (i.e. the mounting status has been changed to READ-ONLY due to a filesystem error), then I'd do the following (assumming ext* filesystems):

```
 tune2fs -e panic [raw-disk-partition-name]
```

EX:

```
 tune2fs -e panic /dev/sda1
```

What this does is panic the system, thus rebooting the server, possibly invoking a fsck on the problem filesystem to fix it.  Thus a serious filesystem problem is handled by having the system fix it automatically, instead of dumping it into Read-ONLY mode which I have not found very helpful.  Besides I'd rather panic a problem filesystem, fixing it than attempting to run with it damaged which as time goes on might cause more damage.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The poster isn't asking how to fix file systems, they are asking how to find read-only file systems.

Additionally, making the system panic is a really bad way to go about fixing a corrupt file system.

Comment: Unfortunately, read-only filesystems due to panic, are *not* marked as "ro" by the mount utility. So this is at least a valuable pointer in a helpful direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /proc/mounts|sort|awk '{print $1 "\011" toupper(substr($4,0,2))}'
```

Produces tab delimited output with mount name and mode.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers suggest, you can parse `/proc/mounts` with `grep` or `awk`, for example you can list the read-only mounts:

```
$ grep "\sro[\s,]" /proc/mounts
```

or

```
$ awk '$4~/(^|,)ro($|,)/' /proc/mounts
```

An alternative to parsing the content of `/proc/mounts` that you could try is

```
$  grep '^ro$' /proc/fs/*/<device>/options
```

where `<device>` is the filesystem's device node name under `/dev`. For example

```
$ grep '^ro$' /proc/fs/*/sdc1/options
```

would return `ro` if `/dev/sdc1` is mounted read-only.

If you want to check for a read-only block device (instead of a mounted filesystem) you can use

```
$ cat /sys/block/<device>/ro
```

which returns `1` if the filesystem is read-only or `0` if read-write.

Note that `<device>` above refers to the real device node. If you want to check a symlink device (such as those created by *device-mapper* or `by-uuid` references) then you can use `basename` and `readlink` to get the device node name. Like these examples:

```
$ grep '^ro$' /proc/fs/*/$(basename $(readlink -f /dev/mapper/foo)/options
$ cat /sys/block/$(basename $(readlink -f /dev/mapper/foo)/ro
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach that works even for remote file systems (which can be mounted rw even if they're exported ro, resulting in a read only file system) is to simply create a test file on each file system and test the return code of that command.

But if this is something that happens regularly you need to look into the cause rather than trying to keep up fixing the symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late but this is how I handle it.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/tmp/test.txt

# Check health of LXD host machine
touch ${FILE}

if [ -f ${FILE} ];
then
   rm ${FILE}
   echo "File System is Good!"
else
   message="File System is R/O !"
   echo ${message} >> /var/log/lxd/health.log >&2
   send_twilio "${TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}" "${TWILIO_ACCOUNT_TOKEN}" "${TWILIO_NUMBER}" "${to_twilio}" "${HOST}" "${message}"
```

Comment: /tmp could be on a different block device than /  ... even in ram (tmpfs)

Answer (score -3):

Just look for the `ro` mount option.

Comment: That miscatches any line with "ro" in it, including anything with the "errors=remount-ro" option.

Comment: So then use a more sophisticated regex.